# How can I stop encoding URL for map coordinates on site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a strange problem which I can't figure out. I have a map that spits out a URL which can be shared and includes coordinates.

https://www.site.blah/map/?openplace=0,0,5500,2890&zoomlevel=1

Wordpress is driving this but when the URL is pasted it the browser bar, it becomes encoded.

https://www.site.blah/map/?openplace=0%2C0%2C5500%2C2890&zoomlevel=0

Replacing the ',' with %2C.

When I embed the map on a separate page like so...

https://www.site.blah/test/map/?openplace=0,0,5500,2890&zoomlevel=1

The URL is fine and not encoded. Works perfectly

I am not sure why when the URL is called from on path down in the URL it's encoded and when it's shown as /test/ it works.

Any ideas what I can do to make this work directly in the root of the site so the root is not encoded too?

Comment: Is there any actual error here that needs fixing, or are you just worried about how it looks? These commas _should_ be encoded, there is nothing wrong with that. If you use URLs that are missing necessary encoding of certain characters, the browser usually fixes that for you - at least in the actual URL it requests; what it shows in the address bar, might differ, and depend on user settings.

Comment: I can’t really reproduce what you are saying though. Please show a proper [mre] of the issue (even if it is just the actually rendered HTML), and also explain in what browser(s) you experience this.

Comment: I understand that it's normal browser behavior to encode the commas. The problem is that by encoding the comma to %2C, the link does not work because the map script does not understand %2C as a coordinate, it needs the commas. 

What I don't get is why does not encode on /test/ but does in the root of the site. The /test/ is working perfectly.

Comment: Sounds like your map script there is what actually needs fixing then. _“What I don't get is why […]”_ - as I already tried to hint at, you are being way too stingy with any actually useful information here, for anyone to be able to say anything definitive about that. It might be due to some particular details of your implementation, but you have not given us anything to work with in that regard. Please go read [ask], and the already mentioned [mre] if you have not done so yet, and then add proper details to your question.

Comment: I am not sure what else to provide as an example. The core is Wordpress, the script is a map plugin which uses javascript and PHP. Neither of which I have coded. The htaccess file is the standard out the box Wordpress with no changes. Server is shared hosting. The above URLs explain the issue and I am not sure why they are acting differently whether it's / or /test. I have tried to clarify the problem in the original question just now.

Comment: Online example then at least? We can hardly tell you what could possibly cause issues, that from their mere description appear to be “inexplicable” in the first place. So if you want to get help, you need to give us something at least, that goes beyond a mere verbal explanation of how the problem presents.

Comment: So here is the problem. Note the URL is encoded

https://www.purecyberpunk.com/map/?openplace=835.4418000600992%2C625.7344628795552%2C2750%2C1445&zoomlevel=1

But not here...

https://www.purecyberpunk.com/map/test2/?openplace=0,0,5500,2890&zoomlevel=1

Comment: There is an explicit redirect involved with the first URL. If I type `https://www.purecyberpunk.com/map/?openplace=0,0,5500,2890&zoomlevel=1` into Chrome’s address bar, then the response is a 301 redirect with `location: https://www.purecyberpunk.com/map/?openplace=0%2C0%2C5500%2C2890&zoomlevel=1`

Comment: If I try the same thing with `foo` instead of `map`, `https://www.purecyberpunk.com/foo/?openplace=0,0,5500,2890&zoomlevel=1` – then it stays on that, no redirect. Not sure if that’s due to the fact that it is a 404, or if there is something special about your `map` page, that causes this.

Comment: (But even if you fix the redirect issue, that will probably not guarantee it will work for all users then; if a user’s browser still decides to encode the commas in its initial request already, your map functionality will still be broken.)

Comment: Yep, that's the problem :) The fact that it's a 404 makes no difference and I do not know why the redirect is happening from the root and not the /test2 or as you say /foo. I need to stop that behavior from happening.

Comment: Not from the root, it appears to be happening for `/map/` only. (Or maybe any existing page, but it is hard to find a different one, almost everything you have in your navigation there appears to only lead to 404 pages as well.)

Comment: OK! Thanks for your help CBroe, the 301 redirect which I didn't notice was a clue.

I manage to fix it by turning WP permalinks to plain in the settings which stops it encoding the URL from the root and recognises everything in the URL. 

Thanks!